# Java - How to ensure correct command line args are entered using try catch?

Tags: java, validation, try-catch

Sorry that I am a noob...

I have a method which takes two specific command line arguments to create an object:

```
Number data = new Number(arg[0], arg[1]);
```

The acceptable arguments are:

- `arg[0]` can only be: `10`, `20` or `30`.
- `arg[1]` can only be: `2`, `4` or `6`.

How do I create a try and catch exception which ensures that two arguments have been provided and that the arguments are acceptable?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Why `try-catch` in particular, and not `if-else`?

Comment: your question is not clear, 1st verify the size of args array `if(args.length==2)` and then proceed

Comment: @Susmit Agrawal how will that work? if the user enters the incorrect args or no args the program will stop and display an error. Im trying to prevent this from happening

Answer (score 2):

You definitely do not control the flow using `try-catch` - it's bad practice. For this reason, there is `if-else` statement.

```
boolean conditionArg0 = arg[0] == 10 || arg[0] == 20 || arg[0] == 30;
boolean conditionArg1 = arg[1] == 2  || arg[1] == 4  || arg[1] == 6;

if (conditionArg0  && conditionArg1) {
    // input is fine, go on
} else {
    // display error
}
```

You should check first if the array `arg` has at least 2 values, otherwise, the `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

In case of more allowed values is better to use `Set<Integer>` and search if the value is present. If the allowed values follow a pattern (ex. divisible by 10), then it's better to use the calculation instead of the `Set`.

---

Edit: Why is controlling the flow using `try-catch` considered a bad practice? It has been discussed many times [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/107723/281026) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why). There are a lot of arguments and I find the most important that (took from [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/107727/281026)):

> Exceptions are for exceptional situations, not for normal flow control. One should use exception handling for handling unanticipated/exceptional situations, not as normal program flow, because otherwise, an uncaught exception will tell you much less.

Semantically, the use of `if-else` is a clean way to control the flow. You should always start with `if-else` and refactor in case the number of compared elements increase significantly.

Comment: I think you should explain why _it's bad practice_. And why _if-else_ is better.

Comment: @snr: Right, thank you :) I have edited my answer pointing to the reasons. I don't want to spend the vast majority of my answer why it's (not) a bad practice but give a solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments,

1. First check if the length of the inputs is exactly 2.
2. Check for equality.

Code:

```
if(arg!=null && arg.length==2){
    if( (arg[0].equals("10") || arg[0].equals("20") || arg[0].equals("30"))
       && (arg[1].equals("2") || arg[1].equals("4") || arg[1].equals("6")) ) {
         Number data = new Number(arg[0], arg[1]);
    }
    else{
        //Handle wrong input(s)
    }
}
else{
    //Handle wrong input(s)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By creating your custom exception class but it is not good idea. using if else is easy and good